# Is there a tool for adding double quotes around ALL elements of a CSV?

Tags: csv

I hava a CSV file that I want to treat as source code.  Essentially I want to take the csv lines and use them as if they were calls to a function with all string parameters.

The problem is, the individual elements are only double quoted when there is a comma in the text.

Is there a quick way of adding the double quotes all elements in a csv row.

The original document is an excel file so anything in excel would be fine, but other quick tools would be welcome.

Comment: Source code in what language? Sounds like you are generating code but might be easier for the code to load the CSV. Depends on what libraries you can use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the Excel CONCATENATE() function.  It takes a comma delimitted list of strings or quoted literals...

```
e.g. CONCATENATE("""", A1, """") etc.
```

where A1 is one of your columns.

I frequently do this for one-off SQL inserts, so where you use double-quotes, I write SQL insert statements

Answer (score 6):

Try the following Python script, just for fun.
It adds quotes to strings in the CSV that don't have them already.

This is a really simple approach - you will likely find corner cases that don't work for you (strings with embedded quotes and commas?).  Fix it!

(oh, this can be written in far less lines of code, I know. Not the point here).

```
import sys
import re

def addQuotes( str ):
    matches = re.match( '^".*"$', str )
    if matches == None:
        return '"' + str + '"'
    return str

# Iterate over standard input. NOTE - this isn't line-buffered, don't try using
# this script interactively...
for line in sys.stdin:

    # Remove trailing linefeed.
    line = line.strip()

    # Split the line into parts separated by commas.
    parts = line.split( ',' )

    # Add quotes to each part that doesn't have quotes already.
    newParts = map( addQuotes, parts )

    # Concatenate the parts back to a single line.
    concatParts = ','.join( newParts )

    # And print it.
    print concatParts
```

Pipe the CSV file to this, using something like -

```
 python QuoteCSV.py < input.csv
```

Comment: Nice job, thanks!  fyi.  To pipe the output to a new file, you could use:
`python QuoteCSV.py < input.csv >newfile.csv`

Comment: Excellent! For python3 update last line to ```print (concatParts)```

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your output to use a different field separator?  Ideally you could use something that would never be used in a field value - then it's a simple search & replace problem.

Another option would be to import the CSV into a SQL table and then dump it back out with quotes around all the fields.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using excel this macro will do what you want:

```
    Option Explicit

Public Sub OutputQuotedCSV()
Const QSTR As String = """"
Dim myRecord As Range
Dim myField As Range
Dim vFilename As Variant
Dim nFileNum As Long
Dim sOut As String

'Get a filename to save as
vFilename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(filefilter:="Microsoft CSV files,*.csv", _
Title:="Save as CSV with fields in double quotes")

If vFilename = False Then Exit Sub 'User chose Cancel

nFileNum = FreeFile
Open vFilename For Output As #nFileNum
For Each myRecord In Range("A1:A" & _
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
With myRecord
For Each myField In Range(.Cells(1), _
Cells(.Row, 256).End(xlToLeft))
sOut = sOut & "," & QSTR & _
Replace(myField.Text, QSTR, QSTR & QSTR) & QSTR
Next myField
Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 2)
sOut = Empty
End With
Next myRecord
Close #nFileNum
End Sub
```

the link in the macro refers to the original source

Answer (score 0):

## Python3 script

```
import sys
import csv

csvwriter = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
reader = csv.reader(sys.stdin, dialect='excel')
for row in reader:
    csvwriter.writerow(row)
```