# text editor plugin or import utility that can handle both tab-delimited and CSV

Tags: export-to-csv, csv

The FAQ says this is ON topic:

```
   SOFTWARE TOOLS COMMONLY USED BY PROGRAMMERS
```

so I expect it not to be closed! The last time I asked, it was closed as off-topic.

EDIT: the suggested answers that involve Excel are not going to work because *Excel mangles the tab-delimited file on the way IN*. I do not program in Python, and the Python utility there is said not to work with strings with embedded quotes and commas.  I need something that understands RFC 4180.

I need a utility or text-editor plugin that can export to the standard **quoted** comma-delimited format.  I don't want to write it myself, as I have other more pressing code to write.

This format (a standard CSV variant for decades) puts double-quotation marks around strings, but leaves numbers alone, and it separates fields with commas, and allows commas in the data (that's why strings are quoted).

Recent versions of Excel do not add double-quotes around strings; older versions did.

If you know of a SOFTWARE TOOL USED BY PROGRAMMERS that performs this task with aplomb, please advise.

Comment: What format are you trying to export to CSV?

Comment: The most frequent is tab-delimited. A legacy import routine is expecting the double-quoted CSV format. So the utility would either have to guess at datatypes, or allow the developer to specify the type column-by-column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a tool for adding double quotes around ALL elements of a CSV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374566/is-there-a-tool-for-adding-double-quotes-around-all-elements-of-a-csv)

Comment: @GGG: see my edit.  When IMPORTING the tab-delimited file into Excel, Excel mangles the file (zipcodes with leading zeros have the zero stripped, for example).  Excel used to be very good at this. Not any more.  I just have too many of these files to be cleaning up such import errors, so I need an intelligent utility that will either quote every field or let me tell it which fields to quote per  RFC 4180. Sometimes these files have more than 100 columns.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of the TSV data you are trying to import? I think we'd need to see how it's quoted and whether it has embedded tabs, commas, or quote characters. This should be as simple as a bit of search-and-replacing in your scripting language of choice (if python is out, is perl okay?), but finding a tool that can handle this will just be luck of the draw (did you try google docs though?).

Comment: Here's a small fictitious sample: `John|McDougal|"Mac"|123 Main St|Princeton|NJ|08543||100.88|20130309|biking, hiking`  and instead of the pipe-delimiter one would have a TAB. In the example, there's a nickname "Mac" already in quotation marks, a comma-delimited list, a zipcode with a leading zero, and a null field.

Comment: Got it... and the desired output for that line? I know you touched on it in your question, just want to be absolutely clear :)

Comment: `"John","McDougal",""Mac"","123 Main St","Princeton","NJ","08540","100.88","","20130309","biking, hiking"` is the basic format; sometimes integers and decimals are not quoted, but it's ok if everything is quoted.

Comment: Going by rfc4180 (page 6, point 6) the third column in your TSV should appear like `"""Mac"""`. If that's not the case, I'd assume that nothing is ever quoted in the TSV, and embedded tabs are escaped like `\t` or similar?

Comment: `"` is a single character (U+0022), not two single quotes in succession, ''.   When `"` appears in the data, it is escaped by another `"`, e.g. `""Mac""`. Not `"""Mac"""`.

Comment: White space and tabs are considered part of the data and should appear inside U+0022 (" foo TAB foo") where TAB is the tab character.

Comment: Tim, yes, but the outer quotes are there to enclose the field. So, `"""Mac"""` ~ `"Mike ""Mac"" McDonald"`. According to rfc4180 (which admittedly a TSV is not), if the field has quotes in it, it must be quoted. "Mac" should become """Mac""" afaik. Anyway, sed seems to handle it nicely, will make an answer out of it.

Comment: OK, I see, you were escaping and surrounding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `sed` tool to accomplish this. Given your example, assuming pipes are tabs:

> John|McDougal|"Mac"|123 Main St|Princeton|NJ|08543||100.88|20130309|biking, hiking

And your desired output: *

> "John","McDougal","""Mac""","123 Main St","Princeton","NJ","08540","100.88","","20130309","biking, hiking"

This can be done by:

- Replacing `"` with `""`
- Replacing tabs with commas surrounded by quotes
- Wrapping each line in quotes
- Trimming trailing empty lines

With `sed`, it's just a matter of doing this:

```
sed 's/"/""/g; s/\t/","/g; s/^\|$/"/g; /^"$/d' < in.tsv > out.csv
```

The GnuWin project maintains a `sed` port for Windows [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

<sub>* I think you need `"""Mac"""` rather than `""Mac""` as discussed above.</sub>

Comment: I am unfamiliar with sed but will look into it. Thanks. Would the code above go through the file line by line?

Comment: @Tim yes, [here's a simple explanation](http://www.dreamwvr.com/sed-info/sed-faq-2.html#ss2.5). Sed performs each operation (3 substitutions and one deletion) on each line from stdin and sends the result to stdout, one line at a time. (edit - [here's](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/sed.html) a better explanation.)

Comment: I was hoping to find a utility that can easily go between various data exchange formats ( have found a commercial one ) but will accept this answer as a valid reply to my question. Thanks.